# Joomla SQL error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla2.5

I am getting a SQL error after performing the following query.

```
UPDATE #_menu
SET component_id =
  (SELECT extension_id FROM #_extensions WHERE name = "com_joomlaupdate")
WHERE title = "com_joomlaupdate"

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET component_id = (SELECT extension_id FROM #_extensions WHERE name = "com_jo' at line 2
```

I am trying to follow the Joomla example here.

[Joomla SQL](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Update_Missing_in_from_Admin_Menu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an underscore in your table name:

`#_menu` >> `#__menu`

so you final code should be:

```
UPDATE #__menu
SET component_id =
  (SELECT extension_id FROM #__extensions WHERE name = 'com_joomlaupdate')
WHERE title = 'com_joomlaupdate'
```

or you're running the code from PhpMyAdmin, then use the following:

```
UPDATE jos_menu
    SET component_id =
      (SELECT extension_id FROM jos_extensions WHERE name = 'com_joomlaupdate')
    WHERE title = 'com_joomlaupdate'
```

Dont forget to change `jos` to whatever you're database table prefix is

Comment: No that was not it. It's a pitty joomla don't have the correct information on their web site !

Comment: ahh are you running this query in PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: The SQL version is 5.5.23-55

Comment: Fixed !! this is the code I needed. UPDATE j16_menu
SET component_id =
  (SELECT extension_id FROM j16_extensions WHERE name = 'com_joomlaupdate')
WHERE title = 'com_joomlaupdate'

Comment: Note NO double underscore with the table name ! Also double quotes are fine also. no need for single .. Thank you so much.